# Automatically determine whether to use spaces or tabs

Tags: vimrc, indentation, filetype-python

I like to use tabs for indentation (hey, don't bully me!). But [33% of other programmers prefer spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-tabsspaces).

[The norm with Python is to use spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) for indetation. Even so, I configured Vim to use tabs with Python since I recently worked on Python code that was indented with tabs. But right now I'm working on some other Python project which has spaces for indentation...

So now I want to make Vim figure out which kind of indentation the file uses and indent accordingly. So my question is how can I accomplish that?

I discovered the `copyindent` option, which seems to solve the problem. But I am unsure whether this is the correct way to solve the problem. Does it have any pitfall? Is there a better way to do this?

---

For the sake of completeness, these are the contents of my `.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` file, which is the one ensuring tabs are used for Python right now. I also have `filetype plugin indent on` in my `.vimrc`.

```
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal textwidth=80
setlocal smarttab
setlocal noexpandtab
```

Comment: It depends somewhat on how robust you want this indentation detection to be. A simple solution would be to assume that leading tabs exist in a file only if tabs are used for indentation. Then you could do something simple like `if search('^\t', 'wn') | setlocal noexpandtab | else | setlocal expandtab | endif`, where you could replace those `|`s by newlines in your plugin.

Comment: Tim Pope had the same problem, and came up with [a solution](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth).

Comment: @SatoKatsura, I installed sleuth.vim and have been using it. It seems to work really well. Please consider writing an answer.

Comment: @GonçaloRibeiro And then have a moderator chastise me for posting a "link-only answer" and asking me to "summarise the link"?  Thanks, but no thanks.  To be fair, I haven't seen that happen on [vi.se] yet, but there are a few trigger-happy, rabidly anti-links moderators on [so].  Caveat emptor.

Comment: As a fellow Pythonic tab-lover, a little heads-up: newer version of Vim need `autocmd FileType python setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 noexpandtab`, as `ftplugin/python.vim` overwrites this. I sent a message to the mailinglist about this, but it didn't get changed, so well :-/